# Plausibility of a planetary ocean containing both $H_2O$ and a form of potassium?

Tags: planets, atmosphere, chemistry, biochemistry

To give a bit of context, I'm trying to tackle a challenge I set out for myself in writing up a speculative biosphere wherein complex land life emerges, without the advent of photosynthesis at all. As a replacement for it, I was considering small exothermic reactions via extracting potassium from liquid "water" and then mixing it with $H_2O$.

Of course, there are numerous problems with this - the most obvious being that potassium and water simply don't mix. I know that certain potassium compounds are insoluble, but to my knowledge they are man-made and not natural. Are there any other potassium compounds that could occur naturally, and to such an extent as to coexist in large quantities with $H_2O$? If not, are there any other natural compounds that contain hydrophobic substances that would work?

Comment: ??? Sea water contains about about 0.4 grams of potassium per liter. Harvesting sea weeds, burning them and leaching the ashes has been the main source of potash for millennia. Even today, Israel and Jordan use vast evaporation pans to extract millions of tons of potash per year from the waters of the Dead Sea. So yes, the ocean does indeed contain potassium compounts,

Answer (score 5):

Not the way you're implying.

Potassium (metal) has a powerfully exothermic reaction with water, forming potassium hydroxide (which is cheerfully soluble) and hydrogen gas, which *also* generally does exciting things during the reaction.

If something is generally inclined to react with water, any compound in which it does *not* react with water is going to require as much (or more, because entropy) energy to separate it for the reaction as you'd get out of it.

So either you need an external source of energy (in photosynthesis, sunlight, in chemosynthesis, generally geologic processes) continually creating the substance you can use to react with water, or you're going to need to find a different energy pathway.

Comment: (Speaking generally, you need a non-chemical energy source feeding into an ecosystem, because any chemical source isn't going to last long enough for self-assembling chemistry to bootstrap its way up to "life".)

Answer (score 0):

Creation of metallic potassium and reacting it with water would appear to be extremely inefficient to say the least, if it is possible at all. Given the vastness of the possibilities available to chemistry and biochemistry it can't be ruled out entirely as there are ways of protecting reactive materials and chemical species. But any such mechanisms would not be known to us any more than we would be able to predict the detailed mechanisms of photosynthesis without having seen any examples. But there are much easier ways.

"a biosphere wherein complex land life emerges, without the advent of photosynthesis at all"

It is believed by some scientists that life on Earth first emerged by use of external proton gradients near deep sea vents. So life without photosynthesis is entirely possible via chemosynthesis in its various manifestation

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemosynthesis

Complex land life would be a little more problematic, but should be possible with a little imagination.